# Android Studio Navigation- bottom menu does not work

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation, android-viewbinding

I am using the following in android  studio

1. View binding
2. Navigation
   The bottom menu when clicked the app does not go to new destination

Here is the code:
App level `build.gradle file`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.3"
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version "2.44" apply false
}
```

Module level `build.gradle file`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "com.google.dagger.hilt.android"
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.newsapiclient'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newsapiclient"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField("String","API_KEY", MY_KEY)
        buildConfigField("String","BASE_URL",MY_URL)

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding =  true
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // ViewModel utilities for Compose
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.10.0"
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

navigation xml file (`nav_graph.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/newsFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.newsapiclient.NewsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_news"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newsFragment_to_infoFragment"
            app:destination="@id/infoFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/saveFragment"
        android:name="com.example.newsapiclient.SaveFragment"
        android:label="fragment_save"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_save" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_saveFragment_to_infoFragment"
            app:destination="@id/infoFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/infoFragment"
        android:name="com.example.newsapiclient.InfoFragment"
        android:label="fragment_info"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_info" />
</navigation>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView)  as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    }
}
```

bottom navigation menu (`bottom_menu.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/newsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_live_tv_24"
        android:title="News Headlines" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/saveFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_save_24"
        android:title="Save News" />
</menu>
```

When I click on the bottom menu bottom, the app does not display the second destination in navigation graph whichhas id `fragment_save`.

Comment: Please fix your question first. `nav_graph` & `activity_main` shows same code.

Comment: @DHAVALA. thanks for pointing this out.  I have corrected my question

Answer (score 0):

You missing code to link bottom navigation with nav controller.

Add below code in `onCreate` method of your `MainActivity`.

```
val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view)
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: Great. If it works, accept the answer, so other developers who are facing same issue can get help out of it.